# Find time in milliseconds?

Tags: powershell, timespan

How can I find the time in milliseconds using PowerShell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In PowerShell you can cast a time value to a timespan and call the [TotalMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
([TimeSpan]"00:05:00").TotalMilliseconds # Returns 300000

([TimeSpan] (Get-Date).ToShortTimeString()).TotalMilliseconds # Returns total milliseconds from 00:00:00 till now
```

Comment: can you refer me any good book for learn powershell scripting ? i'm really thankfull

Comment: If you need to cast an initial value with sub-second precision you can use the following:
`( [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(0.9780526) ).TotalMinutes # return  0.0163`

Comment: The 2nd line gives me `Cannot convert value "11:20 AM" to type "System.TimeSpan". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan."`

Answer (score 57):

You can get the full date with milliseconds with the following:

```
Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss.fff
```

Comment: He used markdown  for the code. It starts and ends with a back-tick. `

Answer (score 17):

The question suggests finding a given datetime in milliseconds (Microsoft epoch time). This is easily solved with:

```
[Math]::Round((Get-Date).ToFileTime()/10000)
```

or

```
[Math]::Round((Get-Date).ToFileTimeUTC()/10000)
```

To convert this to Unix epoch time in seconds:

```
[Math]::Round((Get-Date).ToFileTime() / 10000000 - 11644473600)
```

Where 11644473600 is the number of elapsed seconds between the Microsoft epoch (January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.)) and the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970, 12AM UTC/GMT)

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime(v=vs.110).aspx](http://ToFileTime)

Comment: Microsoft counts 100 nanosecond intervals since its epoch, this needs to be converted into milliseconds.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
[DateTimeOffset]::UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

returns

```
1624186843769
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need (sub-)millisecond resolution, check out [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

```
$stopwatch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$stopwatch.Start()
$stopwatch.Stop()
$stopwatch
```

Answer (score 0):

[Vignesh Narendran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856985/vignesh-narendran)'s answer gives the Epoch milliseconds time in UTC.

If you want it in your computer's time zone, as a string:

```
(Get-Date -UFormat %s).Replace('.', '').Substring(0, 13)
```

As a number:

```
[Long](Get-Date -UFormat %s).Replace('.', '').Substring(0, 13)
```

PowerShell 7.1 added a [-AsUTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.1#-asutc) switch for `Get-Date` if you want UTC.

Comment: Powershell 5.1 is in local time, and powershell 7 is in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

10,000 ticks is 1 millisecond.  (1 tick is 100 nanoseconds.)  Whether it has to be in UTC is another question.  Microsoft ticks and filetime and unix time all count from different dates.

```
(get-date).ticks/10000 # local time (I'm EST -5:00)

63808255598664.8


([datetime]'1/1/2023').ticks/10000

63808128000000


([timespan]10000).TotalMilliseconds

1


([datetimeoffset]'1/1/2023').ticks/10000      # from 1/1/0001 local time

63808128000000


([datetimeoffset]'1/1/2023').ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() # from 1/1/1970 utc

1672549200000


([datetimeoffset]'1/1/2023').ToFileTime()/10000 # milliseconds from 1/1/1601 utc

13317022800000



([datetimeoffset]'1/1/0001').ticks

0


([datetimeoffset]'12/31/1969 7pm').ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()

0


([datetimeoffset]'12/31/1600 7pm').ToFileTime() # ticks

0
```